# Setting the column data type in databases

Tags: anylogic

[Error for written code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLbU3.png) Current model imports certain parameters from an excel file. Hoping to allow users to override the existing values in the database through an editbox. However, I'm faced with the error (shown in attached image). The imported data is column type is in integer type, while the set function requires input of double type. I've tried placing (double) db_parameters.duration_sec and it fails too. Is there any way to replace an imported data to the data type that is required? Will not want to manually change the data type under the database fields as I may need to re-import the excel sheet from time to time which will auto reset the columns back to integer type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```java
update(db_parameters)
    .where(db_parameters.tasking.eq("Receive Lot"))
    .set(db_parameters.duration_sec, (int)v_ReceiveLot)
    .execute();
```

the `(int)` has to be on the paremeter not on the column.